# Authenticate users and manage their resources in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure

I would like to create an MVC application, where users can be authorized with their Azure subscription and after that my application can manage their resources hosted in Microsoft Azure (VM-s, Web Sites, etc.)

My idea is to create a new Active Directory in my subscription. Under the AD, I create an application. At the Configure tab of that application I gave permission to Windows Azure Service Management API and delegated the Acccess Azure Service Management (preview) permission.

To authenticate the user I need the Client ID, the Redirect URL and the Tenant ID from here.

My question is that with this method can I authenticate every user and manage their resources? I would like to use the Windows Azure Management Libraries for .NET nuGet to perform these operations.

I don't want to ask them to upload the publishsettings file, I would like to authenticate them with the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow written [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx).

Is my workflow correct? Can I authenticate every user and manage thir resources in this way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. If I am not mistaken, your clients need to do this in their AD i.e. grant `Subscription Management` access to your application.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, what do you think, how can I solve this issue? How can I get my users subscription and manage their resources within that?

Comment: Based on my understanding from reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx, your users would need to do the same you're planning on doing which I mentioned in my answer above. Other option would be for them to provide you with publish settings file.